# Ошибка в использовании делегатов. В выводе элементов массива одни числа, а в вычислении среднего арифметического другие

Tags: c#

Создайте анонимный метод, который принимает в качестве аргумента массив делегатов и возвращает
среднее арифметическое возвращаемых значений методов, сообщенных с делегатами в массиве.
Методы, сообщенные с делегатами из массива, возвращают случайное значение типа int.

```
class Program
{

    delegate int MyDelegate();
    delegate double MyDel(MyDelegate[] a);

    static int GetRandom()
    {
        return new Random().Next(1, 10);
    }
    

    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Введите число элементов массива: ");
        int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 50));

        var array = new MyDelegate[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            array[i] = () => new MyDelegate(GetRandom)();
        }

        MyDel d =  delegate(MyDelegate[] a) 
        {
            double sr = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
            {
                sr += a[i]();
            }
            return sr / array.Length;
        };

        Console.WriteLine("Среднее ариф = {0}", d(array));
        Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 50));

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(array[i]());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Быть может потому что они всегда случайные? При каждом ввзове деленат возвращает случайное число. Если вы вызовете оди и тот же делегат дважды, вы получите 2 разных числа. Ничего необычного, ваш код работает как и должен.

Comment: Вы можете 3 раза вызвать `d(array)` и 3 раза получить разный результат. Так и должно быть.

Comment: получается статическое поле нужно ?

Comment: Зачем оно вам нужно? Насколько я вижу, задача решена верно, если выкинуть из кода хвост после вывода в консоль. Хотите результат в переменную записать, напишите `int result = d(array);` и готово.

Comment: Что бы вывести те числа которые были в подсчете среднего арифметического, их же где то хранить нужно

Comment: В задании про массив чисел ничего не написано. Зачем он вам?

Comment: Хочу сделать для себя, вот не знаю как..

Comment: Для себя - модифицируйте метод GetRandom так чтобы он выводил возвращаемое число в консоль.

Comment: Блин, спасибо огромное, что то сразу об этом и не подумал)))

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы получить на экран список чисел, использованных для вычисления результата, нужно было добавить в метод `GetRandom()` вывод на консоль сгенерированного значения.

```
static int GetRandom()
{
    Random random = new Random();
    int number = random.Next(1,10);
    Console.WriteLine(number);
    return number;
}
```

Comment: Вот еще что заметил, вынесите создание класса `Random` за пределы метода. `private static Random random = new Random();`, а в методе уберите. Не нужно создавать новый генератор на каждое число.

Comment: да тоже верно))